# Rails schema.rb different for different databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, postgresql, activerecord

I have a problem with schema.rb in Rails.  If i run `rake db:migrate` the results are different for different databases, to be precise if I use PostgreSQL and a text field it gives me

```
t.text     "summary"
```

line, but with SQLite it gives me

```
t.text     "summary",    :limit => 255
```

Also when I use `:default`, number of spaces differ, PostgreSQL:

```
t.boolean  "watched",    :default => false, :null => false
```

SQLite:

```
t.boolean  "watched",                   :default => false, :null => false
```

It is quite annoying that when I run `rake db:migrate` on production it changes my schema.rb and obviously I can't use `rake db:schema:load` on production when using schema.rb generated in development environment.  My question is why are there differences and how do I make them disappear, so schema.rb is the same for production and development?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your own sanity, I'd recommend using the same DB engine in development as you do in production. It doesn't take too much effort to get up and running with a local PostgreSQL server, and you'll avoid some nasty surprises by doing all of your development and testing on the same backend you're using in production.

Comment: Not exactly an answer I was looking for, but it's a good piece of advice.  I'll just use PostgreSQL in development too, thanks.

Comment: The differences between DBs are numerous and subtle, and Rails does *not* provide a completely sealed abstraction around the DB — nor is it meant to. Using the same DB in dev and production is an absolute must.

Comment: Perhaps "absolute" is a little strong, but the effort required is minimal, and the pain you can avoid could potentially be significant.